# Create DLL (run-time link library) for Standard C/C++ Library

Tags: c++, c, gnu, scientific-computing

Is it possible to create DLL (run-time link library) for Standard C/C++ Library like GNU Scientific Library, LibModbus, GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library, LibQrEncode using Mingw that can be linked at run-time? If yes, how?
Using the make method creates files that can only be statically linked.

Why this is being done :

1. Separating user files/code from standard library
2. Multiple user program/process working independent/minimal synchronization from each other access similar set of functions but are developed by 3 separate developers
3. Modifying and updating files will be simpler

Comment: Libraries listed have nothing to do with [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) or [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the exact library. Usually you just pass a flag to the build system.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to convert most (if not all) static libraries to dlls somehow. If it is supported by the build, you should read the documentation from the vendor. If it is not, you can dig in and change the make file as required - either way, for all the libraries list, this is a very broad question. Possibly start with one, and when (or if) you encounter an error, then come back and ask about that.